# IO function to print Chars with (>>)

Tags: haskell

[Thinking Functionally in Haskell](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/computer-science/programming-languages-and-applied-logic/thinking-functionally-haskell) presents the following function:

```
f :: String -> IO ()
f xs = foldr (>>) (return ()) (map putChar xs) >> putChar '\n'
```

I'm confused by the `foldr (>>)`.

```
ghci> :t foldr (>>)
foldr (>>) :: Monad m => m b -> [m a] -> m b
```

It looks like the purpose of using `(>>)` here was to "lift" `Monad m` onto the remaining `foldr` arguments, no?

Could this function have been written without using `>>`?

Comment: `foldr (>>) (return ())` is [better known as `sequence_`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E+[m%28%29]+-%3E+m%28%29).

Answer (score 5):

In the context of the IO monad, `>>` performs one action followed by another, without passing any data between. It's just bind (`>>=`) for when you don't care about the return value.

`putChar x`, where `x` is some Char, has type `IO ()`. It's an IO action that returns `()` ('nothing'). `map putChar xs` takes a list of characters and returns a list of IO actions, all of which return 'nothing'.

By `foldr`ing this list with `>>`, we're just performing each action in sequence, not caring about any intermediate results. As @leftaroundabout noted in the comments, this is commonly expressed with `sequence_`.

And yes, we certainly could write this without using `>>`.

```
f' :: String -> IO ()
f' [] = return ()
f' (x:xs) = do putChar x
               f' xs
-- or
f [] = return ()
f' (x:xs) = (putChar x) >> f' xs
-- or
f' xs = sequence_ $ map putChar xs
```

**Edit:**

@rampion makes a good point in the comments that I've only really obscured the `>>`. In all three of those cases there's a `>>` somewhere behind the scenes. Here's the function written using the normal bind operator, `>>=`.

```
-- same base case
f' (x:xs) = putChar x >>= \_ -> f' xs
```

But again I've cheated and just expanded the definition of `>>` in terms of `>>=`. We're composing functions inside of a monad. We have to use `>>=` or `>>=` somewhere, otherwise why use a monad?

Comment: without typing `>>`, but it's worth noting that `do { putChar x ; f' xs }` is desugared by the compiler to your second case.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose I write `f "hey"`. We begin with a `String`

```
f "hey"
```

which is really a `[Char]`

```
f ['h', 'e', 'y']
```

and we substitute it into the definition of `f`

```
foldr (>>) (return ()) (map putChar ['h', 'e', 'y']) >> putChar '\n'
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

where we generate a list of actions to print the characters `[IO ()]`

```
foldr (>>) (return ()) [putChar 'h', putChar 'e', putChar 'y'] >> putChar '\n'
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and use `foldr` to sequence them together using `>>`

```
putChar 'h' >> putChar 'e' >> putChar 'y' >> return () >> putChar '\n'
```

which is the desugared version of `do` statements that don’t bind return values with `<-`

```
do
  putChar 'h'
  putChar 'e'
  putChar 'y'
  return ()
  putChar '\n'
```

So `>>` or an equivalent function is required, because what this function is doing is building up an `IO` action that prints each character in the `String` you give it, exactly as if you had written a series of statements in `do` notation.

Of course, this is a common thing to do, so `foldr (>>) (return ())` is called `Control.Monad.sequence_` and `sequence_ . map f` is called `Control.Monad.mapM_ f`.

Answer (score 0):

> Could this function have been written without using `>>`?

There are three ways to answer to this.  The first one is: yes, it could have been implemented with `>>=`, because `>>` can be reduced to `>>=`:

```
a >> b = a >>= \_ -> b
```

The second one is: not really, because any real implementation in Haskell is going to bottom out to `>>` or some way of writing `>>` it in terms of `>>=`.

The third, and much more complicated answer is: yes, in a sense, because this function fundamentally doesn't use the full power of monads, only that of *monoids*.  `IO ()` is a monoid with `>>` as its associative operation and `return ()` as its identity element.  So what the function is doing, fundamentally, is what the [`foldMap` operation from the `Foldable` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) does—reduce the list to a single value by mapping the element type to an appropriate monoid.

You take the sum of a list of persons' salaries by mapping each person to their salary and folding with `+` and `0` monoid.  You print a sequence of characters by mapping each character to the `IO ()` action that prints it and then folding with the `>>` and `return ()`.